# Knockout refresh viewModel using mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, mapping

I am trying refresh a small widget with knockout and the mapping plugin. Here is my code so far:

```
var AppViewModel = function (data, total, qty) {
    var self = this;
    self.Products = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    self.CartTotals = ko.observable(total);
    self.TotalQty = ko.observable(qty);
};

var func = function(u) {
    return $.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: "{}", dataType: "json", url: u });
},
getQtyTotal = function(b) {
    var a = 0;
    $.each(b.Table.Rows, function(c) {
        a += parseInt(b.Table.Rows[c].Quantity) || 0;
    });
    return a;
};

$.when(func("/store/MiniCart.aspx/GetShoppingCartInfo"), func("/store/MiniCart.aspx/GetCartTotal")).done(function (jsonA, jsonB) {
    var ds = $.parseJSON(jsonA[0].d), ds2 = $.parseJSON(jsonB[0].d), qtyTotal = getQtyTotal(ds);
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(ds, ds2, qtyTotal));
});

<div class="cartDropDownProductItemWrapper" data-bind="foreach: Products.Table.Rows">
    <div class="cartDropDownProductItem">
        <div class="cartDropDownProductImg">
            <img id="cart_details_rpt_prod_image_0" style="height: 71px; width: 55px;" data-bind="attr: { src: ProductImageURL }">
        </div>

        <div class="cartDropDownProductDesc">
            <h6><a data-bind="text: ModelName, attr: { href: ProductLink }"></a></h6>
            <div class="cartDropDownProductDescInner">
            <div class="cartDropDownColor"> COLOR 
                <strong><span data-bind="text:ColorName"></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="cartDropDownSize"> SIZE
                <strong><span data-bind="text: SizeName"></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="cartDropDownSize"> QTY 
                <strong><span data-bind="text: Quantity"></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="cartDropDownPrice"> PRICE 
                <strong><span data-bind="text: UnitCost().toFixed(2)"></span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="cartDropDownRemove">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" onclick="removeItem('v3BuhngpE4c=')">
                    <img src="/images/layout/icons/remove.gif" alt="Remove Item">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<!-- end fo reach -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="cartDropDownButtons clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="countItems"><span data-bind="text: TotalQty"></span> Items</li>
        <li class="subTotal" id="subTotal">SUBTOTAL: $<span data-bind="text: CartTotals().toFixed(2)"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It renders fine intially but when I try to rebind on a jQuery click event and call:

```
   ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(ds, ds2, qtyTotal));
```

It duplicates the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you start off by creating an empty viewModel... which takes no arguments via it's constructor, like so:

```
function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

...Then you can reference it by name to load in your data using ko.mapping, like this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({ "PropertyName": plainJsObject }, {}, viewModel);
```

What this does is runs the **ko.mapping magic** on plainJsObject, and stuffs the result into a property (in this case, called PropertyName) on your viewModel object.

**The part you would particularly care about is this:**

If you want to refresh the data located in the viewModel.PropertyName with fresh data from the server... you just call the exact same method, and it updates that same property on your viewModel.  Just call this same thing again, with new values in your plainJsObject:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({ "PropertyName": plainJsObject }, {}, viewModel);
```

Since you have (I assume) already performed your ko.applyBindings() at some point in your code, this line above will immediately update your view.

Comment: And that is why SO works so well. nearly three years after you posted this, it helped me straight away after a 10 second google search.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to perform the binding once so just keep that outside of any event driven function calls.

```
 ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(ds, ds2, qtyTotal));
```

I think you are over complicating your code in the above example. I would just return set of Product objects which contains properties for description, unit price, quantity etc and then to calculate the total, use a ko computed variable which will update automatically if a user tries to increase/decrease quantity.

```
function Product(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.description = ko.observable(item.description);
    self.quantity = ko.observable(item.quantity);
    self.unitPrice = ko.observable(item.unitPrice);
    self.total =  ko.computed(function() {
        return self.quantity() * self.unitPrice();
    });
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.overvallTotal =  ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.products().length; i++) {
            total += self.products()[i].total;
        }
        return total;
    });        
    self.removeProduct = function(item) { self.products.remove(item) };

    // Load initial state from server, convert it to Product instances
    $.getJSON("/store/MiniCart.aspx/GetShoppingCartInfo", function(allData) {
        var mappedProducts = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Product(item) });
        self.products(mappedProducts);
    });    
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

You will have to adjust your server side json results to work with this.

Comment: Thats what I assumed. On pageLoad my data renders correctly. Lets say I have two products in my cart, the cart will display 4 products, each prodcut displaying twice. I'm I suppose to refresh or clean my ViewModel?

Comment: @user1933368 I've posted a simpler solution for you above. If you still can't solve it maybe put everything into a jsFiddle project and include that in your question.

Comment: If the answer of the JSON call should be turned into a model through the mapping plugin, is it allowed to self.products(mappedProducts)